# AVCaptureVideoDataOutput videoSettings with kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey

Tags: ios, avfoundation, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to get openGL compatible buffers from camera.
I am setting up AVCaptureVideoDataOutput like this:

```
_videoDataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
  [_videoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_sessionQueue];
  //  NSArray *pixelsFormats = _videoDataOutput.availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes;
  [_videoDataOutput setVideoSettings:@{
    (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
    // Flag to enable emitting openGL frames from camera.
    (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey : @(YES)
  }];
  _videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
```

But I get this error:

```
[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:] - videoSettings dictionary contains one or more unsupported (ignored) keys: (
    OpenGLESCompatibility
)
```

Can I use kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?
If not what is the best way to emit openGL compatible frames from camera?

I have already considered creating CVOpenGLESTextureRef from CVImageBufferRef, but that needs a buffer copy from CPU to GPU. I am trying to avoid that.

Note: I tried removing kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA from settings. But still get same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to also add an empty `kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey`

```
(NSString*) kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey : @{}
```

as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1781/_index.html)

However I don't think you should shy away from `CVOpenGLESTexture`s. On iOS GPU and CPU memory is unified, so texture cache copies are (probably) free!

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware that on iOS GPU and CPU share same address space.